# Is there a way to use Retrofit faster?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, httprequest

I am developping an android application and I use retrofit to send and get the data from a server. However, the http post request that I use took 800 ms on average. The server side works fast, it looks like there is no problem there. I want to reduce the timestamp to maximum 400 ms, could you describe a technic to do it or could you provide any resources?

Here is my code on android studio, thanks on advance...

this is the function that I apply the put request to the server:

```
public static void getEntries(int subjectID, int commentID, int userCode){
    Retrofit retrofit=ApiClient.getRetrofit();
    Call<List<Entry>> call=retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class).getEntries(subjectID,commentID,userCode);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Entry>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Entry>> call, Response<List<Entry>> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                System.out.println("code: "+response.code());
                return;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Entry>> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

This is the interface that I created:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("showEntries.php")
Call<List<Entry>> getEntries(@Field("subjectID") int subjectID,
                             @Field("commentID") int commentID,
                             @Field("userCode") int userCode);
```

}

This is the singleton pattern to get retrofit instance:

```
public class ApiClient {
private static final String BASE_URL="someurl";
private static Retrofit retrofit=null;

public static Retrofit getRetrofit(){
    if(retrofit==null){
        Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

Finally, this is my model class:

```
public class Entry {
@SerializedName("subjectID")
private String subjectID;

@SerializedName("commentID")
private int commentID;

@SerializedName("dateTS")
private String dateTS;

@SerializedName("comment")
private String comment;

@SerializedName("usercode")
private int userCode;

@SerializedName("likepoint")
private int likePoint;

@SerializedName("dislikepoint")
private int dislikePoint;

@SerializedName("likestatu")
private String likeStatus;

public Entry(String subjectID,int commentID, int userCode){
    this.subjectID=subjectID;
    this.commentID=commentID;
    this.userCode=userCode;
}

public Entry(String subjectID, int commentID, String dateTS, String comment, int userCode, int likePoint, int dislikePoint) {
    this.subjectID = subjectID;
    this.commentID = commentID;
    this.dateTS = dateTS;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.userCode = userCode;
    this.likePoint = likePoint;
    this.dislikePoint = dislikePoint;
}
```

Comment: Did you try making the same call using a tool like Postman as a speed comparison?

Comment: No I did not, Thanks for your advice